# Minimal sufficient for $X \sim Pois(\beta_o+\beta_1x_i;x)$

Tags: statistics, sufficient-statistics

Find the minimal sufficient statistics for $y_i, i = 1, ..., n$ are independent Poisson with mean $\mu_i$ with $$\log(\mu_i) = \beta_o+\beta_1 x_i$$
where $x_i$'s are known predictors and $(\beta_0,\beta_1)$ are unknown parameters.

What I have done:
$$\begin{align}X &\sim Pois(\log(\mu_i);x) \\
\implies L(\log(\mu_i);x) &= \prod_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{\log(\mu_i)^x\mu_i}{x!}\right) \\ &= \frac{\log(\mu_i)^{nx}\mu_i^n}{\prod_{i=1}^nx!} \end{align}$$

Where to go from here?

Comment: What is the joint pmf of $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ when $Y_i\sim \text{Poisson}(\mu_i)$ independently?

Comment: @StubbornAtom because they're independent then $\left(\log(\mu_i)^{nx} \mu_i^n\right) \left(\prod_{i=1}^n x! \right)^{-1}$